# java.sql.SQLException: Column 'JOB_ID' not found

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am using Java8 with JPA2/Hibernate5, Spring4 and mySQL.

If anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

I have the following tables.

```
+--------+          +------------+        +---------+
| job    |          | person_job |        | person  |
+--------+          +------------+        +---------+
|  ID    |          |  JOB_ID    |        |   ID    |
|        |          |  PER_ID    |        |         |
+--------+          +------------+        +---------+
```

A `person` can have many `jobs`.

**Job.java**

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "person_job", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "PER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", unique = true) })
private Person person;
```

The following SQL works fine when I run it directly against the database:

```
select
         e.*, p.*
     from
         www.job as e  
     inner join
         www.person_job as pj 
             on e.id=pj.JOB_ID  
     inner join
         www.person as p 
             on pj.PER_ID=p.ID  
...
```

When I run a native query (with the above sql), I get the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Column 'JOB_ID' not found.

In **Job.java**, if I swap the `JOB_ID` and `PER_ID` around in the `@JoinTable`, then I get:

> java.sql.SQLException: Column 'PER_ID' not found.

Because the above SQL runs fine against the database, I think the problem is with join configuration in **Job.java**.

---

**UPDATE**

I also have the following that works correctly:

```
+--------+          +--------------+        +----------+
| job    |          | job_location |        | location |
+--------+          +--------------+        +----------+
|  ID    |          |  JOB_ID      |        |   ID     |
|        |          |  LOC_ID      |        |          |
+--------+          +--------------+        +----------+
```

A `job` can have many `locations`.

**jobs.java**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "job_location", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "LOC_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", unique = true) })
private Set<Location> locations;
```

**UPDATE**

I only get this error when I execute a native query. When I do the following fr example, it works perfectly.

```
    return (T) entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
```

Is there something wrong with my native query? (This query works if I don't have the `person` column on `Jobs.java`).

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(" select e.* ");
    sb.append(" from ");
    sb.append("    www.job as e ");
    //sb.append(" inner join www.person_job as pj on e.id = pj.JOB_ID ");
    //sb.append(" inner join www.person as p on pj.PER_ID = p.id ");
    sb.append("  where e.id = :id ");
    Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sb.toString(), JobWithDistance.class);
    q.setParameter("id", id);
    List<Job> jobs = (List<Job>) q.getResultList();
```

Adding the 2 commented out lines makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION:

I needed to change:

```
sb.append(" select e.* ");
```

to

```
sb.append(" select * ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
// in Job entity
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "person_job", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ID") }, 
                                inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PER_ID") }
)
private Person person;

...

// in Person entity
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
private List<Job> jobs;
```

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer. Can you try with these changes?

Comment: I get: `SQLException: Column 'PER_ID' not found.`  I think this is doing the same as my original set up.

Comment: Anything else in the stacktrace? Anything that would indicate where is Hibernate looking for `PER_ID` column?

Comment: `(default task-2) Column 'PER_ID' not found. SQLGrammarException: could not execute query  java.sql.SQLException: Column 'PER_ID' not found.
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1094)`

Comment: I would think it is coming from:  `@JoinColumn(name = "PER_ID")` because if I remove the `person` column from the `Jobs.java` I get no errors.

Comment: The example with `locations` which works for you, is it a unidirectional or bidirectional relationship? (regarding `PER_ID`) Yes, but it is not clear in which table Hibernate looks for that column, because if it was looking for it in `person_job` it would have found it. Maybe that's not even that important but it would indicate a bug IMHO.

Comment: I just tested it with only having the `job` column on the `person.java` and I works with no errors. My problem is I need the `person` in the `jobs` object.  `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinTable(name = "person_job", joinColumns = {
   @JoinColumn(name = "PER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
     @JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", unique = true) })
 private Set<Job> jobs;` seems like the `@OneToMany` is working, but `@ManyToOne` is not.

Comment: `locations` is unidirectional and `@OneToMany`. I will investigate and then try answer your question about the `PER_ID`.  In my case I only need a unidirectional `@ManyToOne` join, but this is what is not working.

Comment: I cannot see where Hibernate is looking for the `PER_ID`. There is no indication apart from the error above.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360626/bidirectional-one-to-many-with-jointable) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671776/how-to-make-a-one-to-many-bidirectional-relation-with-jpa-annotations-where-the). It is possible that this type of bidirectional relation is not supported, but in these threads there are answers where `@JoinTable` is put on both sides of the relation. To me, this is strange, because I think Hibernate will treat this as two separate mappings.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look.

Comment: I try the same as them but still get the error. I also tested this on a mere, where it doesn't use a native query, and it inserts to the database correctly. Maybe it means there is a problem with my native query sql. But this runs fine directly against the database, and also when I remove the column from the Jobs object. - very confused.